# What are the chances of encountering a shiny Ultra Beast?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation, pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I always wanted a shiny Kartana, so I soft reset Kartana all the time. I've been doing this for about four days now at 5000 light years. But I never find one, what is the chance?

Answer (score 1):

Kartana can be randomly found as a shiny with the same base chance as every other Pokémon that can be shiny: 1/4096.

Comment: But I thought that getting farther in the wormhole gives better shiny chance?

Comment: @SlimeDJ21channel You asked that already

Comment: I know but she said it’s 1/4096 so I thought it would be more

Comment: Ultra beasts and legendaries are 1/4096 as mentioned, but also note that they are affected by shiny charm, so with shiny charm they are 1/1024. Ultra beast/legendary shiny rate is not affected by the distance you travel as far as I am aware, unlike the normal Pokemon you find in wormholes.